# Converting XML to DOT

Tags: c#, graph, converting, xml

I would like to show an XML tree as a tree using GraphViz Dot tool. Then I must convert it to a [DOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) file.

It is what I have tried

```
    string dot = "digraph G {" + Environment.NewLine;
    XML2DOT(XmlRoot, "r");
    dot += Environment.NewLine + "}";
    ....
    private void XML2DOT(XmlNode n, string id)
    {
        if (n == null)
            return;
        string NodeName = n.Name.Replace("-", "_");
        if (n.HasChildNodes)
        {
            dot += Environment.NewLine + NodeName 
                + id + "[label=\"" + NodeName + "\"];";
        }
        else
        {
            dot += Environment.NewLine 
                + "leaf" + id + "[label=\"" + n.InnerText + "\"];";
        }
        int i = 0;
        foreach (XmlNode item in n.ChildNodes)
        {
            string cid = id + i;
            dot += Environment.NewLine + NodeName + id + " -> " 
            + (item.HasChildNodes ? item.Name.Replace("-", "_") : "leaf") 
            + cid + ";";
            XML2DOT(item, cid);
            i++;
        }
   }
```

The input xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S>
<MN clitic="empty" ne_sort="pers">
   <PUNC clitic="empty">
      <w clitic="empty" gc="Ox" lc="Ox" lemma="#">#</w>
   </PUNC>
   <MN clitic="empty" ne_sort="pers">
      <N clitic="ezafe">
         <w clitic="ezafe" gc="Apsz ; Nasp--- ; Nasp--z ; Ncsp--z" lc="Nasp--z" lemma="مسعود" n_type="prop" ne_sort="pers">مسعود</w>
      </N>
      <N clitic="ezafe">
         <w clitic="ezafe" gc="Apsy ; Nasp--- ; Nasp--z ; Ncsp--y" lc="Nasp--z" lemma="شجاعی" n_type="prop" ne_sort="pers">شجاعی</w>
      </N>
      <N clitic="empty">
         <w clitic="empty" gc="Nasp--- ; Nasp--z" lc="Nasp---" lemma="طباطبایی" n_type="prop" ne_sort="pers">طباطبایی</w>
      </N>
   </MN>
   <PUNC clitic="empty">
      <w clitic="empty" gc="Ox" lc="Ox" lemma="#">#</w>
   </PUNC>
</MN>
</S>
```

And it is what I get:

[image]

It works as expected, just would like to know a more general and efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 6):

There's an XML syntax for DOT called DotML at http://martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/. Generating a generic DotML tree from XML is very straightforward using XSLT. Most of it is just:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <node id="{generate-id()}" label="{name()}"/>
  <edge from="{generate-id(..)}" to="{generate-id()}"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <node id="{generate-id()}" label="{.}"/>
  <edge from="{generate-id(..)}" to="{generate-id()}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not concatenate strings like this, it's inefficient. Instead, use a `StringBuilder`.

---

I'm unclear on how is the method supposed to be used. In the usage, it looks like `dot` is a local variable, while in the method itself, it looks like it's a field. If you want to stick with `string`, return it from the method. If you're going to switch to `StringBuilder`, accept it as a parameter.

Also, the whole process, including `digraph`, should be encapsulated into a method.

---

The scheme you're using for producing unique node IDs does not actually produce IDs that are unique. For example `r + 1 + 0` produces the same ID as `r + 10`.

A simple solution would be to have a single `i` for the whole conversion.

---

You have some small pieced of code that repeat. Especially if you can use C# 6.0 expression bodied methods, I would extract them into separate methods.

---

Your code does not handle XML elements with no content (e.g. `<elem />`) well: it presents them as empty text nodes.

---

What does `cid` mean? Child ID? Don't abbreviate names unnecessarily.

---

The common convention in C# is to use camelCase for local variables, you mostly follow that, except for `NodeName`, which should be `nodeName`.

Also, 3-letter abbreviations are almost always not fully capitalized (e.g. it's `XmlNode`, not `XMLNode`), you should follow that convention too: `Xml2Dot` instead of `XML2DOT`.

And `XML2DOT` is not a great method name either. Method names should usually be verbs.

---

The final result could look like this:

```
class XmlToDotConverter
{
    private const string Leaf = "leaf";

    private readonly StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    private int i;

    public string Convert(XmlDocument document)
    {
        stringBuilder.Clear();

        stringBuilder.AppendLine("digraph G {");

        ConvertNode(document.DocumentElement, i);

        stringBuilder.Append('}');

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private static string ConvertName(XmlNode node)
        => node.Name.StartsWith("#") ? Leaf : node.Name.Replace("-", "_");

    private void AppendNode(string name, int id, string text)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine($"{name}{id}[label=\"{text}\"];");

        // or the following, if you care about performance more than about readability

        //stringBuilder
        //    .Append(name)
        //    .Append(id)
        //    .Append("[label=\"")
        //    .Append(text)
        //    .Append("\"];")
        //    .AppendLine();
    }

    private void AppendEdge(string fromName, int fromId, string toName, int toId)
        => stringBuilder.AppendLine($"{fromName}{fromId} -> {toName}{toId};");

    private void ConvertNode(XmlNode node, int id)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            string nodeName = ConvertName(node);
            AppendNode(nodeName, id, nodeName);

            foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                i++;
                int childId = i;
                AppendEdge(nodeName, id, ConvertName(childNode), childId);
                ConvertNode(childNode, childId);
            }
        }
        else if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            AppendNode(Leaf, id, node.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```